# Is it possible for Compass to output files to multiple locations from Grunt?

Tags: sass, gruntjs, compass-sass

I have a SCSS build working from Grunt that takes files in a "build" directory and outputs them to a "deploy" directory.

Is it possible to split off a single file -- the primary CSS file -- and have it output not only to the deploy directory but also on to a production server?  That's the only file that will be changed now that the site is live.

I know Capistrano can do something like this, but it's probably not worth it on our end to add more technology to the workflow.  So is it possible within Grunt?

Comment: Better not having the compass grunt contrib do this for you but you using a grunt contrib to copy the deploy file on the production server with the protocol you wan't.

Comment: Why is it "Better not having the compass grunt contrib do this for you?"

Comment: In a modular world, one care about optimizing, one care about replicating. But, it's only conceptual concerns. Moreover it is a solution to your issue. Ho, yeah your question is: "is it possible to ..", so there I can't answer ;)

Comment: Oh yes, I agree with you completely.  Believe me when I tell you it's not me who's asking that we do this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than modify the configuration of your css generation task which could result in a second copy being compiled, you can utilize an additional entry under `grunt-copy`:

```
styles: {
    expand: true,
    dot: true,
    cwd: 'deploy/styles',
    dest: 'other/styles',
    src: 'filename.css'
}
```

Take care that you aren't calling the entire copy task elsewhere in your Gruntfile, and when you call this instance you'll use `'copy:styles'`.

Comment: Will this work across a network or is that another question entirely?  The idea is to push the resultant CSS file into its home directory on the server.

Comment: That would depend on what transports are available. There are many grunt plugins that allow for the use of various transports (file, sftp, WebDAV, etc.)

Comment: Thanks Jason!  I see what I have to do now.